# GUI interface for company specific calculator

Tags: python, python-2.x, calculator, gui, tkinter

I created a customised GUI application in Python, which is a calculator that does some basic functions for my company. I would like to ask you for overall suggestions for code improvement.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Mar 20 17:18:39 2018

@author: Dimitar Dimov
"""

import PIL
import Tkinter
import Tkinter as Tk
from math import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image


class pmvCalculator(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *args):
        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args)
        self.parent = parent
        self.main = Tk.Frame(parent)
        self.main.grid(row = 0, column = 0)      
        self.initialise()

    def initialise(self):
        self.v = 0
        self.v2 = 0
        self.v3 = 0
        self.v4 = 0
        self.v5 = 0
        self.v6 = 0 
        self.v7 = 0
        self.v8 = 0
        self.houseValue = 40
        self.fivestoreyBuildingValue = 50
        self.tenstoreyBuildingValue = 60
        self.fifteenstoreyBuildingValue = 70

        self.grid()
        self.insertLogo()

        self.dropdownMenus()

        Tk.Button(self, text = "Show Options", command = self.buttonTwoPress).grid(row = 13, column = 2, pady =10)

        self.pmvcalcPicture()

    def insertLogo(self):
        self.logoFrame = Tk.Frame(self)
        self.path = PIL.Image.open("cast.gif.png")
        self.img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.path)
        Tk.Label(self, image = self.img).grid(row=1, column = 2, columnspan=4, rowspan=3, padx = 50, pady = 15)

    def dropdownMenus(self):
        self.dropdownFrame = Tk.Frame(self)
        choicesBuilding = {'House', '5 Storey Building', '10 Storey Building', '15 Storey Building'}
        choicesConstr = {'Traditional', '2-D', '3-D'}

        self.tkvar1 = Tk.StringVar(self)
        self.tkvar2 = Tk.StringVar(self)

        Tk.Label(self, text = "Enter your preferred type of building: ").grid(row=9, column = 2, sticky = Tk.W )
        Tk.OptionMenu(self, self.tkvar1, *choicesBuilding).grid(row=9, column = 3)

        Tk.Label(self, text = "Enter your preferred type of procurement: ").grid(row=11, column = 2, sticky = Tk.W)
        Tk.OptionMenu(self, self.tkvar2, *choicesConstr).grid(row=11, column = 3)

        return self.tkvar1, self.tkvar2

    def buttonTwoPress(self):        
        self.choice2()
        Tk.Button(self, text = "Calculate", command = self.fivestoreyBuilding).grid(row = 33, column = 2, pady =10, sticky = Tk.E)

    def choice2(self):    

        self.pmvar1 = self.tickBox("P-M Foundations", 15)
        self.pmvar2 = self.tickBox("P-M Frame Elements", 16)
        self.pmvar5 = self.tickBox("P-M Roof Solutions", 17)
        self.pmvar6 = self.tickBox("P-M Internal Walls", 18)
        self.pmvar7 = self.tickBox("P-M Doorsets", 19)
        self.pmvar8 = self.tickBox("P-M Bathrooms/ Kitchens", 20)
        self.pmvar9 = self.tickBox("P-M Wiring Solutions", 21)

        if self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building":
            self.pmvar10 = self.tickBox("P-M Plant Rooms", 22)
        else:
            self.tickBox("                                                         ",22)

        if self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building":
            self.pmvar11 = self.tickBox("P-M Risers", 23)
        else:
             self.tickBox("                                            ",23)

        if self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building":
            self.pmvar12 = self.tickBox("P-M HIU's", 24)
        else:
            self.tickBox("                                          ",24)

        if self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building":
            self.pmvar4 = self.tickBox("P-M SIPS Facades", 25)
        else:
            self.tickBox("                                                        ",25)

        if self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building":
            self.pmvar3 = self.tickBox("Large Format Facade Materials", 26)
        else:
            self.pmvar3 = self.tickBox("                                                     ",26)

        if self.tkvar2.get() == "2-D":
            self.pmvar13 = self.tickBox("P-M Structural Systems inclduing Insulation:", 27)
        else: 
           self.pmvar13 = self.tickBox("                                                                          ", 27)

        if self.tkvar2.get() == "2-D":
            self.pmvar14 = self.tickBox("P-M Facade Solution", 28)
        else:
            self.pmvar14 = self.tickBox("                                                     ", 28)

        if self.tkvar2.get() == "3-D":
            self.pmvar15 = self.tickBox("P-M Core", 29)
        else:
            self.pmvar15 = self.tickBox("                                                     ", 29)    

        if self.tkvar2.get() == "3-D":
            self.pmvar16 = self.tickBox("P-M Integrated Modular Facade", 30)
        else:
            self.pmvar16 = self.tickBox("                                                       ", 30)

        if self.tkvar2.get() == "3-D":
            self.pmvar17 = self.tickBox("P-M Common Areas (Unfurnished)", 31)
        else:
            self.pmvar17 = self.tickBox("                                                             ", 31)    

        if self.tkvar2.get() == "3-D":
            self.pmvar18 = self.tickBox("P-M Common Areas (Furnished)", 32)
        else:
            self.pmvar18 = self.tickBox("                                                         ", 32)    


    def fivestoreyBuilding(self):

        if self.pmvar1.get() == True:
            self.v = 0.5
        else:
            self.v = 0
        if self.pmvar2.get() == True:
            self.v2 = 3
        else:
            self.v2 = 0

        if self.pmvar3.get() == True:
            self.v3 = 0.5
        else:
            self.v3 = 0

        if (self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building" and self.pmvar4.get() == True):
            self.v4 = 3
        else:
            self.v4 = 0

        if self.pmvar5.get() == True:
            self.v5 = 1
        else:
            self.v5 = 0
        if self.pmvar6.get() == True:
            self.v6 = 1
        else:
            self.v6 = 0
        if self.pmvar7.get() == True:
            self.v7 = 1
        else:
            self.v7 = 0
        if self.pmvar8.get() == True:
            self.v8 = 2
        else:
            self.v8 = 0
        if self.pmvar9.get() == True:
            self.v9 = 0.5
        else:
            self.v9 = 0
        if (self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building" and self.pmvar10.get() == True):
            self.v10 = 1
        else:
            self.v10 = 0

        if (self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building" and self.pmvar11.get() == True):
            self.v11 = 1
        else:
            self.v11 = 0

        if ( self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building" and self.pmvar12.get() == True):
            self.v12 = 1
        else:
            self.v12 = 0

        if (self.tkvar2.get() == "2-D" and self.pmvar13.get() == True):
            self.v13 = 0.5
        else:
            self.v13 = 0

        if (self.tkvar2.get() == "2-D" and self.pmvar14.get() == True):
            self.v14 = 1.5
        else:
            self.v14 = 0

        if (self.tkvar2.get() == "3-D" and self.pmvar15.get() == True):
            self.v15 = 0.5
        else:
            self.v15 = 0

        if (self.tkvar2.get() == "3-D" and self.pmvar16.get() == True):
            self.v16 = 5
        else:
            self.v16 = 0

        if (self.tkvar2.get() == "3-D" and self.pmvar17.get() == True):
            self.v17 = 7
        else:
            self.v17 = 0

        if (self.tkvar2.get() == "3-D" and self.pmvar18.get() == True):
            self.v18 = 10
        else:
            self.v18 = 0

        if (self.tkvar1.get() == "House"):
            self.houseValue = 40
        else:
            self.houseValue = 0

        if (self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building"):
            self.fivestoreyBuildingValue = 50
        else:
            self.fivestoreyBuildingValue = 0

        finalPMV2 = Tk.IntVar()  
        finalPMV2 = (self.houseValue + self.fivestoreyBuildingValue
                     + self.v + self.v2 + self.v3 + self.v4 + self.v5
                     + self.v6 + self.v7 + self.v8 + self.v9 + self.v10 + self.v11 + self.v12
                     + self.v13+ self.v14+ self.v15+ self.v16+ self.v17 + self.v18)
        Tk.Label(self, text = '{} %'.format(finalPMV2)).grid(row = 33, column =3, pady=10)
        return finalPMV2

    def pmvcalcPicture(self):

        self.path2 = PIL.Image.open("pmv_calc.png")
        self.path2 = self.path2.resize((600,300), Image.ANTIALIAS) 
        self.path2.save('update_pm_image.ppm', 'ppm')
        self.img2 = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.path2) 
        Tk.Label(self, image = self.img2).grid(row=14, column = 6, columnspan=3, rowspan=30, padx = 20, pady = 15)

    def tickBox(self, label, newrow):
        var = Tk.IntVar()
        Tk.Checkbutton(self, text = label, variable = var).grid(row = newrow, column = 2,sticky = Tk.W)
        return var

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tk.Tk()
    root.title("Cast PMV Calculator")
    root.geometry("1100x800")

    app = pmvCalculator(root)

    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I  would like to receive a review on the computation part if possible. That would help me structure my thoughts and become a better programmer. thank you for your time and attention! I appreciate it very much.

Comment: I added the [tag:python-2.7] tag based off your imports, feel free to correct it if I’m wrong.

Comment: yes correct - this is python 2.7, written in Spyder IDE

Comment: Please share links to those images you used

Comment: Just hide the image if you try to run the code, its not really important. The mechanics of the calculator are what and code design are what I'm after

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you could simplify some if-statements by doing `if self.pmvar1.get():`
 instead of `if self.pmvar1.get() == True:` since the `if` will verify whether the condition is True by itself.

Furthermore, if I didn't miss something it's possible to merge some `if` statements within `choice2` into one because `if self.tkvar1.get() == "5 Storey Building":` seems to be repeated quite often. But, as I said, I'm really tired right now and maybe there is a reason I just didn't see.

Comment: The reason why I repeat them is because upon choosing a different option from the dropdown menu and then pressing the button "Show Options", some of the checkboxes appear or disappear. 

I was thinking of smarter way to do this - perhaps linking a new frame to different options in the dropdown ("House", "5 Storey" etc) and invoking a function to show/hide the frame, however, I didn't know how to code it.

Answer (score 1):

## naming

`self.v8` is very unclear in what it does. The same goes for `buttonTwoPress` and some of the other function names. The names of the functions and variables are part of the documentation, so use clear names. Also, try to follow Pep-8.

## parametrize

You have 3 building types and some 20 options. Instead of hard-coding the name and cost of each of those in the GUI code, it is better to keep those settings somewhere else in a configuration

```
BuildingOption = namedtuple('BuildingOption', ['name', 'cost'])
BUILDING_TYPES = OrderedDict([
    ('house', {
        'cost': 40
    }),
    ('5 Storey Building', {
        'cost': 50,
        'options': [
            BuildingOption('P-M Plant Rooms', 1),
            BuildingOption('P-M Risers', 1),
            BuildingOption("P-M HIU's", 1),
            BuildingOption('P-M SIPS Facades', 1),
            BuildingOption('Large Format Facade Materials', 1),
        ],
    }),
    ('10 Storey Building', {
        'cost': 60,
    }),
    ('15 Storey Building', {
        'cost': 60,
    }),
])

GENERAL_CHOICES = [
    BuildingOption('P-M Foundations', 1),
    BuildingOption('P-M Frame Elements', 1),
    BuildingOption('P-M Roof Solutions', 1),
    BuildingOption('P-M Internal Walls', 1),
    BuildingOption('P-M Doorsets', 1),
    BuildingOption('P-M Bathrooms/ Kitchens', 1),
    BuildingOption('P-M Wiring Solutions', 1),
]
CONSTRUCTION_CHOICES = {
    'Traditional': [],
    '2-D': [
        BuildingOption('P-M Structural Systems including Insulation:', 1),
        BuildingOption('P-M Facade Solution', 1),
    ],
    '3-D': [
        BuildingOption('P-M Core', 1),
        BuildingOption('P-M Integrated Modular Facade', 1),
        BuildingOption('P-M Common Areas (Unfurnished)', 1),
        BuildingOption('P-M Common Areas (Furnished)', 1),
    ],
}
```

this way you can keep the thickboxes in a dict `self.tickboxes` option as the key.
The options can be accessed with these helper functions

```
def get_building_options(building_type):
    return BUILDING_TYPES[building_type.get()].get('options', [])


def get_construction_options(construction_choice):
    return CONSTRUCTION_CHOICES[construction_choice.get()]
```

## populate dropdown

I renamed `dropdownMenus` tot `populate_dropdown`, and used the keys of the building types and construction choices as items. I gave `tkvar1` and `tkvar2` also more clear names.

```
def populate_dropdown(self):
    self.dropdownFrame = Tk.Frame(self)

    building_type = Tk.StringVar(self)
    construction_choice = Tk.StringVar(self)

    Tk.Label(self, text='Enter your preferred type of building: ').grid(row=9, column=2, sticky=Tk.W)
    Tk.OptionMenu(self, building_type, *BUILDING_TYPES.keys()).grid(row=9, column=3)

    Tk.Label(self, text='Enter your preferred type of procurement: ').grid(row=11, column=2, sticky=Tk.W)
    Tk.OptionMenu(self, construction_choice, *CONSTRUCTION_CHOICES.keys()).grid(row=11, column=3)
    return building_type, construction_choice
```

## populating tickboxes

I renamed `choice2` to populate_tickboxes, and it can be as simple as:

```
def populate_tickboxes(self):
    self.clear_tickboxes()
    tickboxes = (
        GENERAL_CHOICES
        + get_building_options(self.building_type)
        + get_construction_options(self.construction_choice)
    )
    for row, option in enumerate(tickboxes, 15):
        self.tickboxes[option] = self.make_tickbox(option.name, row)
def show_options(self):
    self.populate_tickboxes()
    Tk.Button(self, text='Calculate', command=self.calculate_cost).grid(row=33, column=2, pady=10, sticky=Tk.E)
```

If you want to group the tickboxes into the different types, that should be quite easy too

### clear the tickboxes

To clear the tickboxes, you also need a reference to the tickbox, and not only to the var, so I changed `self.tickBox` to:

```
TickBoxTuple = namedtuple('TickBox', ['var', 'tickbox'])
def make_tickbox(self, label, newrow):
    var = Tk.IntVar()
    tickbox = Tk.Checkbutton(self, text=label, variable=var)
    tickbox.grid(row=newrow, column=2, sticky=Tk.W)
    return TickBoxTuple(var, tickbox)
```

Then clearing the tickboxes becomes as simple as:

```
def clear_tickboxes(self):
    while self.tickboxes:
        _, tickbox = self.tickboxes.popitem()
        tickbox.tickbox.destroy()
```

## calculate cost

I renamed `fivestoreyBuilding` to `calculate_cost`.
The function to calculate the costs is then this very concise.

```
def calculate_cost(self):
    total_cost = sum(tickbox.var.get() * option.cost for (option, tickbox) in self.tickboxes.items())
    total_cost += BUILDING_TYPES[self.building_type.get()]['cost']
    Tk.Label(self, text='{} %'.format(total_cost)).grid(row=33, column=3, pady=10)
    return total_cost
```

## **init**

I try to declare all instance variables in the `__init__`. That way it is clearest

```
def __init__(self, parent, *args):
    Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args)
    self.parent = parent
    self.main = Tk.Frame(parent)
    self.main.grid(row=0, column=0)
    self.tickboxes = {}

    self.grid()
    self.logo = self.insert_logo()
    self.logo.grid(row=1, column=2, columnspan=4, rowspan=3, padx=50, pady=15)

    self.option_button = Tk.Button(self, text='Show Options', command=self.show_options)
    self.option_button.grid(row=13, column=2, pady=10)

    self.dropdown_frame, self.building_type, self.construction_choice = self.populate_dropdown()

    self.pmv_calc_picture = self.add_pmv_calc_picture()
    self.pmv_calc_picture.grid(row=14, column=6, columnspan=3, rowspan=30, padx=20, pady=15)

def insert_logo(self):
    logoFrame = Tk.Frame(self)  # is this used?
    path = PIL.Image.open("cast.gif.png")
    img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(path)
    return Tk.Label(self, image=img)

def add_pmv_calc_picture(self):

    path = PIL.Image.open("pmv_calc.png")
    path = path.resize((600, 300), Image.ANTIALIAS)
    path.save('update_pm_image.ppm', 'ppm')
    img = PIL.ImageTk.PhotoImage(path)
    return Tk.Label(self, image=img)
```

## summary

All in all, in this code, way too much is hardcoded. Learn to use the correct data structure. The things I changed are just a few suggestions. You can seperate the presentation and logic a lot further, perhaps by the inclusion of a few Classes

My complete attempt can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/vadella/211cc103ea0102292a6a4b4fa6681422)